# connect to Wireguard with react native

Tags: react-native, openvpn, wireguard

I want to build an application using react native the UI is not that hard for me I can handle it my main problem is I can not make the application interact with the VPN configs file that I have from Wireguard
can you guys please guide me to make my react native app interacts with the phone VPN API  so I can connect the configs file to it

Answer (score 1):

I also want to build VPN with React NATIVE, but i Can't find proper library.

I Found this but i think old VERSION
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vpn-testing-only

Comment: The response is not an answer. Does not solve the problem, but just annotates it

Comment: it is so hard to find sources about this topic, the problem is I got -1 on the question

Answer (score -4):

To integrate WireGuard VPN configurations into your React Native application, you can follow these steps:

1. **Install Required Libraries**:

   Start by installing the necessary libraries for React Native and VPN handling. You can use libraries like `react-native-vpn` (for Android) or `react-native-network-vpn` (for iOS). Install them using npm or yarn:

   ```
   npm install react-native-vpn
   ```

   or

   ```
   yarn add react-native-vpn
   ```

   Follow the library's documentation for installation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-openvpn
2. **Handle Permissions**:

   Ensure your app has the necessary permissions to access VPN configurations. For Android, request the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission in your AndroidManifest.xml. For iOS, add a usage description for VPN access in your Info.plist file.
3. **Implement VPN Logic**:

   Create a component or module to manage VPN connections within your React Native app. This module should:

   - Import the VPN library and configure it with your WireGuard configuration settings.
   - Implement logic to start and stop the VPN connection.
   - Handle VPN status and connection events.

   Here's a simplified example using `react-native-vpn`:

   ```js
   import VPN from 'react-native-vpn';

   const wireguardConfig = {
     // Your WireGuard configuration settings here
   };

   // Start VPN connection
   const startVPN = async () => {
     try {
       await VPN.start(wireguardConfig);
       console.log('VPN connected');
     } catch (error) {
       console.error('VPN connection failed:', error);
     }
   };

   // Stop VPN connection
   const stopVPN = async () => {
     try {
       await VPN.stop();
       console.log('VPN disconnected');
     } catch (error) {
       console.error('VPN disconnection failed:', error);
     }
   };
   ```
4. **User Interface Integration**:

   Create user interface components (e.g., buttons) to allow users to initiate and terminate VPN connections. Attach the `startVPN` and `stopVPN` functions to the `onPress` events of these components.

Please note that VPN integration can be complex and may vary based on your specific use case and network setup. Consult the documentation of your chosen VPN library for additional guidance, and consider seeking expert assistance if necessary.

Remember to follow best practices for securing VPN configurations and user data to maintain the security and privacy of your application.

---

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541